# Search data in array of json array using django filter

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, django-filter

I am using Postgresql DB.

I have a JSONField in my Model.

Here is the json.

```
        object.outer_data = [
            {
                'end': '20-11-2020 02:01 PM',
                'start': '20-10-2020 02:01 PM',
                'inner_data': [
                    {
                        'type': 'primary',
                        'id': '2'
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'secondary',
                        'id': '8'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'end': '',
                'start': '20-11-2020 02:01 PM',
                'inner_data': [
                    {
                        'type': 'primary',
                        'id': '2'
                    },
                    {
                        'type': 'secondary',
                        'id': '6'}]
            }
        ]
```

And I want to find out if this data have a matching key `'dietitianid': '6'`.

```
Models.objects.filter(outer_data__dietitians__inner_data__contains=[{'dietitianid': '6'}])
```

But ofcourse this is wrong as I have to pass the index in which `inner_data` will be searched.
I am looking for this query where I can sort of use a double `contains`.
One for `dietitians` in `outer_data` and then for `dietitianid` in `dietitians`.

Any suggestion would be helpful!
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more info: where is `dietitianid/dietitians` stored in `object` or `object.outer_data`

Comment: Why do you need that? I have posted the raw data as an example to show the structure of json. Where field is a JSONField and name is "outer_data"